# Should I have to wear oversized clothing because of my shape?

Tags: gender

During a meeting I was informed no form fitting clothing is to be wore. I’m quite  curvy and proportioned very well. However; my shape attracts a lot of attention. However; have to live with my body. I was encouraged after the meeting to always wear a long shirt,sweater, jacket or oversized clothing.
My problem is my clothing or not tight it’s the shape of my body and I have a problem with being told to cover up to make other feel comfortable. How should I honestly feel

Comment: Hey Kali. Is this a new job you are starting? Where are you located and what type of job this is? Do you wish to convey that you feel uncomfortable being told to use certain clothes and would like to dress as you want (of course, keeping it professional)?

Comment: Also, what country are you in? And was everybody told this, or was it just you?

Comment: @DJClayworth im currently located in the United States. Everyone was told no form fitting clothing. I was encouraged to wear something that covers my body and provided with suggestions that will help Remedy the situation such as Carnegie’s long sweaters oversize clothing

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it’s extremely amazing how other women at my job wear what is comfortable to them, which is the same if not similar and they don’t feel pressured. No matter what I wear my hips, bum and boobs will attract attention

Comment: Who was the meeting with? Your boss? HR? A coworker? Did they say why they want you to cover your body?

Comment: You’re certainly not wrong to not like being told how to dress, especially since you’re apparently being singled out on account of your body type. That said, the best course of action might depend on the person’s motivation.  Is this a misguided attempt to help you avoid unwanted attention or do they just have some weird personal issue with how you look?

Comment: @AffableAmbler - I don’t see how the author is being singled out if it’s a blanket policy.  It’s not clear if the policy was created due to the author.

Comment: I have upvoted this question because I think it is a very important subject. Times are changing and we are seeing more and more woman in almost any profession, but clear dress codes are still lacking in many companies. I think that is holding back many woman from reaching their full potential. I hope someone can give some suggestions on how the question can be improved so that it can be opened again.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I honestly feel

However you want. Your honest feelings are yours and cannot be controlled.

Outwardly it depends on who told you to cover up, if it's company policy or a superior then it makes sense to comply. If not then you have more options including it being a sideways compliment on your physique rather than anything else.

Comment: Your perspective actually made me feel better. I appreciate your comment. Sometimes I just wish people could see past the exterior presentation and focus on my work ethic. Being shaped in such away attracts unwanted attention. However; I have to feel good about the skin I’m in. Feeling like a spectacle born for the amusement of others is horrible. It’s not the clothing it’s the fit